# Determine growth rate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Having struggled with calculating the following, I turn to you:

In a model for growth af a certain type of cancer, the quantity of cancer-cells $N$ (measured in millions), can be described as a function of the time $t$ (measured in days). Based on various measurements, the following model is described as the following:
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = 0,82 - 0,88  N.$$
Additionally, $N(10) = 266$.

Determine the growth rate to the time $t = 10$, and elaborate on that.

Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to understand how you are describing this. Are you just saying you have $\frac{dN}{dt} = 88N$, with I.C. $N(10) =266$? The rest were just observations over different periods.

Comment: The phrase, "growth rate to the time $t=10$", doesn't read like something a mathematician would write. Is that the *exact* wording of the question?

Answer (score 1):

That equation is separable:
$$
\int_{N_0}^N \frac{d N}{0.82 - 0.88 N} = \int_0^t d t
$$

Comment: I imagine OP has problems that extend beyond finding the general solution to the differential equation (although no doubt this will get OP off to a good start).